# Replacing characters with PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using the following code to format strings of text and put them inside `<div></div>` tags.

```
<?php

$errors  = '::This is line 1 ';
$errors .= '::This is line 2 ';

$errors = preg_replace('#::(.+?)\s*(?=::|$)#','<li>$1</li>',$errors);

echo ($errors);

?>
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/524310)

What this does is takes the `$errors` string, and turns it into `<li>This is line 1</li><li>This is line 2</li>` removing the `::` that's before each string, and trimming trailing spaces.

I'm trying to add `>>` to the beginning of each result, so it'll be `<li>>>This is line 1</li><li>>>This is line 2</li>`

One way I thought of is to add the `>>` in the second part of the `preg_replace`

`$errors = preg_replace('#::(.+?)\s*(?=::|$)#','<li>>>$1</li>',$errors);`

which works, but is there a way to do it in the first part of the regex itself?

`'#::(.+?)\s*(?=::|$)#'`

I did try tweaking the `regex` in quite a few ways, but end up with all sorts of weird results.

Answer (score 0):

What about it !

```
<?php

$errors  = '::This is line 1 ';
$errors .= '::This is line 2 ';
$errors = str_replace("::","::>>" ,$errors);
$errors = preg_replace('#::(.+?)\s*(?=::|$)#','<li>$1</li>',$errors);

echo ($errors);

?>
```

Comment: That's an additional step. Can't do that. Need to do it in the `preg_replace` itself.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's nothing wrong with your solution (replacing it directly in the function, that is). An alternative would be to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) where you can provide additional functionality.
Here's an example (which - for this purpose - is kind of an overkill, but you get the idea):

```
<?php
$errors  = '::This is line 1 ';
$errors .= '::This is line 2 ';

$regex = '#::(.+?)\s*(?=::|$)#';

$errors = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    // obviously, much more could be done here
    function($match) {
        $prefix = ">>";
        return "<li>{$prefix}{$match[1]}</li>";
    },
    $errors);

echo ($errors);
// output: <li>>>This is line 1</li><li>>>This is line 2</li>
?>
```